# How to make getElementsByClassName work instead of getElementById?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to make it work for all elements: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27uuj/3/)

First element

```
  <p id="tweet1">First long text displayed fully on hover</p>
```

works through

```
   var tweet = document.getElementById('tweet1');
```

The second and third element doesn't work:

```
  <span class="tweet1">Second long text displayed fully on hover</span>

  <span class="tweet1">Third long text displayed fully on hover</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var tweet = document.getElementById('tweet1');
tweet.id = 'tweet1';
tweet.className = 'hiding';

var slide_timer,
    max = tweet.scrollWidth,
    slide = function () {
        tweet.scrollLeft += 2;
        if (tweet.scrollLeft < max) {
            slide_timer = setTimeout(slide, 40);
        }
    };

tweet.onmouseover = tweet.onmouseout = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e = e.type === 'mouseover';
    clearTimeout(slide_timer);
    tweet.className = e ? '' : 'hiding';
    if (e) {
        slide();
    } else {
        tweet.scrollLeft = 0;
    }
};
```

CSS

```
#tweet1 {
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:120px;
}
.hiding {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

When i change in HTML `<p id="tweet1">` to `<p class="tweet1">`, 
in CSS `#tweet1` to `.tweet1` and in JS `var tweet = document.getElementById('tweet1');` to `var tweet = document.gelElementsByClassName('tweet1');`
nothing happens, first element stops to work.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which pretty much looks like an array.

Comment: It's in the name... `getElement` ***`s`*** `ByClassName`

Comment: JQuery's `$("tweet1")` is so much easier... And will give you more samples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML
    First long text displayed fully on hover

```
<p class="tweet1">Second long text displayed fully on hover</p>

<p class="tweet1">Third long text displayed fully on hover</p>
```

CSS

```
 .tweet1 {
   overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
   width:120px;
}
.hiding {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

jQuery/Javascript

```
$('.tweet1').addClass('hiding');

var slide_timer,
slide = function (element) {
    element.scrollLeft += 2;
    if (element.scrollLeft < element.scrollWidth) {
        slide_timer = setTimeout(function(){slide(element);}, 40);
    }

};


$('.tweet1').mouseover(function () {        
    clearTimeout(slide_timer);
        $(this).removeClass('hiding');
        slide(this);
    });

$('.tweet1').mouseout(function () {        
    clearTimeout(slide_timer);
        $(this).addClass('hiding');
        $(this)[0].scrollLeft = 0;
    });
```

To see it in action check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27uuj/34/)

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me a lot. Brilliant work.

Comment: My pleasure mate. Notice that I'm using jQuery

Answer (score 2):

**gelElementsByClassName** gives you a list ..

You would need to iterate over the list and assign the same functionality to each of the  elements in the HTML collection.

```
var tweets = document.getElementsByClassName('tweet1');
for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
    var tweet = tweets[i];
    tweet.className = 'hiding';

    var slide_timer,
    max = tweet.scrollWidth,
        slide = function () {
            tweet.scrollLeft += 2;
            if (tweet.scrollLeft < max) {
                slide_timer = setTimeout(slide, 40);
            }
        };

    tweet.onmouseover = tweet.onmouseout = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e = e.type === 'mouseover';
        clearTimeout(slide_timer);
        tweet.className = e ? '' : 'hiding';
        if (e) {
            slide();
        } else {
            tweet.scrollLeft = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

It is a better idea to extract  the contents of the for loop into a separate function.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27uuj/24/)**

Comment: I've inserted your code in JS and corected HTML, CSS, but it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/27uuj/10/

Comment: That is because you are completely removing the class name tweet.. You need to only toggle the class `hidden`

Comment: Unfortunately, not working as it should work. But someone updating fiddle with jquery and it starts to work as it should be - http://jsfiddle.net/27uuj/30/  My main aim is that it will work as first example on hover - http://jsfiddle.net/27uuj/3/